# Constant single match regex

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I am looking for the name (definition?) of **X** in:

> A regular expression is X iff it has **exactly one possible match**.

Examples: <empty regex>, `abc`, `\.`, `[.]`, `a|a`, `a{8,8}`, `\Q.*?\E` 
Counterexamples: `.`, `a*`, `a|b`, `\d`, `a?`

I would call such a regex **constant**. Can I use this name? Is there a similar concept?

---

Additionally, I would say a regex is **literal** iff it is constant and the single match is equal to the regex itself (f.e. `a` but not `[a]`).

*NB:* I would greatly appreciate some references, because I would like to cite them.

Research done:
[Check if a regex is ambiguous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608993/check-if-a-regex-is-ambiguous) uses "ambiguous" but in another way ("a string can be matched by more that one ways from 1 regex")
I have asked it on [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805682/constant-single-match-regex) but was redirected here.

Comment: Those examples seem to indicate that you are interested in patterns interpreted by various commonly-used regex libraries, rather than regular expressions as part of formal language theory (in which most of those examples are meaningless).

Comment: Yes, it is intended for practical purposes, specifically I want to reason about specific Java regexes (patterns), but I don't really care about the specific regex syntax implementation that much, more about the property of that specific regular expression, a.k.a pattern (not property of regular language) that says: this here regex matches one and only one input.

Comment: Or maybe there is something like "this regex describes a singleton regular language"? Preferably I am looking for somehting less wordy

Comment: $|L(R)|= 1$ :-) I suppose "singleton" covers it fine. I'd say "this regex matches one string" (something which rarely comes up in my experience, but I guess your use case is different).

Comment: Please post an answer (preferably with how would you read that out loud). BTW if you are interested, I need it in the field of DSL construction, where I am essentially reverse-engineering a regex token to know if I can use the single match specially (f.e. as an alias for the concept). Tokens are "singleton" regexes more often than not, actually.

Comment: @Hawk $|L(R)| = 1$ means that the set $L(R)$ which contains all the strings matched by the regex $R$ contains only one element. But did I understand correctly that you basically want to check if a given regex is "constand" (describes a singleton language)? And are looking for an efficient algorithm?

Comment: I am looking for the terminology, not an algorithm. I used [Generex](https://github.com/HawkSK/Generex) to do the test.